# Error in cordova run android

Tags: android, cordova

[image]
Unable to run the cordova app in my android device as I am getting an error while connecting the android device and running the command "cordova run android"

Comment: Are you using Ionic ?

Comment: No its not ionic

Comment: So are you trying to run on emulator?

Comment: @wahabmemon pls add the error text and commands used next time. Images should be avoided on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HarshalDeshmukh no, i just need to run it on my android device

Comment: @pro_cheats yes. sure I'll keep that in mind

Comment: @wahabmemon kindly check the answer and inform if that works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because there was no android device detected though it is connected. You should connect your android device and enable `Developer Options` in `Settings`.

Further enable `USB Debugging` to let cordova install the app into the device. Also u need to select `OK` on pop up message comes up after enabling USB debugging.

Check [this](https://www.howtogeek.com/129728/how-to-access-the-developer-options-menu-and-enable-usb-debugging-on-android-4.2/) for step by step procedure if you are are not getting developer options in settings.

You can get the list of available devices and emulators configured using this command -

`cordova run android --list`

Hope this helps.

Comment: no, its not working. still showing the same errors and i have tried running the command 'cordova run android --list' and it shows:
Available android devices: 
Available android virtual devices:

Comment: Yes it worked. All I needed was to install the proper drivers